# Angular with node.js http failure response for unknown url ): 0 unknown error

Tags: node.js, angular, apache, ssl, https

So let's start with little info in the beginning.
I have nodejs server side app and client app on angular. I send only get requsts to server app just to read data from database. When i started my apps on local machine they were working pretty well. But when i deployed them to server i got such error : (below in screen)

[screen with error from angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGDYe.png)

So, i added cors support in server app and add Allow Headers. [code in nodejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f6PO.png)
But it doesn`t help. When i post "GET" request i get my allow headers in response header and my data that i need in body.

[screen with response headers in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4bOu.png)

[screen with response body in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8uqV.png)

Server - apache. One interesting thing that server app works good with http protocol and when i am using htttps get this errror [error with https](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p71Mc.jpg)
But angular works on https.

Comment: are you sure your server running on 3000 port ?

Comment: I think you could comment `app.use` which you write `res.headers` insie it and app.options and test with the default of cors library and see what you will get first then you add your own options

Comment: @AmolBJamkar Yes, when i post request in POSTMAN to http://serverIP:3000 i get my data

Comment: @Shorbagy Same result